# Configure Winbind to get User Info from Windows

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, active-directory, samba, winbind

I need to configure SAMBA and Winbind on Ubuntu 10.04.1 clients to get their UID, GID, and home directory from Windows Active Directory.

I have Windows Services for Unix installed with the relevant information entered in there (i.e. the UID, GID, shell, etc.).

The problem is that no matter what I try, I cannot get winbind to properly get that information and use it.  I know the problem lies in my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.  Unfortunately I just can't find any decent documentation whatsoever on how to properly set this up.

Below is my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

```
[global]
    security = ads
    realm = DOMAINSERVER.COM
    password server = <<IP.of.domain.server>>
    workgroup = DOMAINSERVER
    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    idmap backend = ad      ## Important
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    template homedir = /home/%U  ## I tried commenting this out, and it didn't work
    template shell = /bin/bash  ## I tried commenting this out, and it didn't work
    client use spnego = yes
    client ntlmv2 auth = yes
    encrypt passwords = yes
    winbind nss info = sfu     ## Important
    winbind use default domain = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
```

I **REALLY** appreciate the help on this one!

**EDIT:** The only other thing I can think of that is causing an issue is the fact that I haven't yet cleared the old winbind mapping stored in the `/var/lib/samba/` directory.  If I clear that out, will that resolve the issue?  BTW, I have begun examining this document, however, its age may be of a problem: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/battista/articles/winbindenterprise/winbindenterprise.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the configuration listed at this location: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/battista/articles/winbindenterprise/winbindenterprise.pdf, I was able to get it working properly (well, for the most part).  The primary task I needed to accomplish was to get each user to obtain their own unique UID, which this implementation does.

I'm not able to retrieve *all* the informaiton from SFU, but I am able to get each user to get a unique UID which is consistent across all machines.  This unique UID is based off of the Windows SID value.

**If someone knows the *true* fix for this, then I'll mark that as the answer.**

For the time being, the configuration for `/etc/samba/smb.conf` worked for me:

```
[global]
    realm = DOMAINSERVER.COM
    workgroup = DOMAINSERVER
    security = ads
    password server = ip.of.pass.server

    idmap uid = 10000-20000
    idmap gid = 10000-20000
    idmap backend = rid:DOMAINSERVER.COM=10000-20000  ## IMPORTANT ##
    allow trusted domains = no                        ## IMPORTANT ##
    template homedir = /home/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash

    winbind use default domain = yes
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind refresh tickets = yes        ## For Kerberos ##
    client use spnego = yes
    client ntlmv2 auth = yes
    encrypt passwords = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
```

After updating the file, I stopped the `smbd` and `winbind` services.  I then navigated to the `/var/lib/samba` directory, and deleted all the files.

Once that was completed, I rebooted my machine, and the UID's were based on the last digits of each user's SID, and I have verified that on multiple machines.

I hope this post was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

On the off chance this helps somebody: the way to get Winbind to notice the Unix login shell and home directory information from Active Directory is by adding the following to `smb.conf`:

```
winbind nss info = rfc2307
```